# Delete image file from Amazon S3

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, delete-file

Here is my code for deleting the image file form `Amazon S3`:

```
<?php

$s3 = new S3(awsAccessKey, awsSecretKey);
$del1 = $s3->deleteObject($bucket,$newfilename);
$del2 = $s3->deleteObject($thumb_bucket,$newfilename);

public static function deleteObject($bucket, $uri)
    {
        $rest = new S3Request('DELETE', $bucket, $uri, self::$endpoint);
        $rest = $rest->getResponse();
        if ($rest->error === false && $rest->code !== 204)
            $rest->error = array('code' => $rest->code, 'message' => 'Unexpected HTTP status');
        if ($rest->error !== false)
        {
            self::__triggerError(sprintf("S3::deleteObject(): [%s] %s",
            $rest->error['code'], $rest->error['message']), __FILE__, __LINE__);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
?>
```

In this, I am ***getting true as output***, but ***form my bucket it is not going to be deleted***. Any solution?

Comment: I also have the same issue